# print monthly calendar given month and year

Tags: c, date

Once the user enters a valid input (two integers separated by a space), print out
the calendar in a format be similar to the output of the UNIX cal command. For
example, if the user enters 03 2014, the output should be:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXG8q.jpg

I realized i asked a similar question to this prior, however i could not understand the answer at all. I feel that i should start from the basics so that i can learn myself how to print out a monthly calendar from the basis when given an input of a month and year.

I have provided code below that can only print out the following month of march, as we incorporate the the fact that each different month of each different year starts on a different day the code becomes ever more complicated so i was wondering how i should even begin to do this code.

Please nothing to advanced as my professor would not like me using things that are far ahead of my level of knowledge.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int k, rmd;

 printf("     March 2014\n");
 printf(" Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa\n");

 for(k=1;k<32;++k){
     if(k==1){
         printf("                   %2d\n", k);
     }
     else if(k%7 == 1){
         printf(" %2d\n",k);
     }

     else{
         printf(" %2d",k);
     }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22522434/971127

Comment: Basically, "nothing too advanced" so your professor may not discover you did not write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is simple:

Find a year for which you know what happens (e.g. 2014-3-1 is a Saturday). Then consider what happens in a year with 365 days (which consists of 7*52 + 1 days...) and a 366 day year. After that you only need to figure out when [leap years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) happen.

You can either find your start date for the first year you will ever consider, or also incorporate backwards computation (e.g. what happened 365 days before this) - the first is simpler, but introduces an additional constraint.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1:  Given the month and year, determine the day of the week for the 1st of the month
Step 1a: You already know how to do that, since I saw one of your previous posts
Step 2:  Compute how many spaces you need to print so that 1 is in the correct column
Step 3:  Print additional numbers until you reach Saturday
Step 3a: Print a newline character after printing the number for Saturday
Step 4:  Keep outputting numbers and newlines till you reach the end of the month
Step 4a: Remember that February has 29 days for leap years
Step 5:  Print a newline if the month didn't end on a Saturday
Step 5a: Print one more newline just for good measure
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054016/c-program-to-find-day-of-week-given-date) to know how to get the day of week. then you can use this code to print the calender of a month `month` of year `year`.

```
d=2+ ((153 * (month + 12 * ((14 - month) / 12) - 3) + 2) / 5)+ (365 * (year + 4800 -((14-month) / 12)))+ ((year + 4800 - ((14 - month) / 12)) / 4)- ((year + 4800 - ((14 - month) /12)) / 100)+ ((year + 4800 - ((14 - month) / 12)) / 400)- 32045;
d=d%7;
i=0;
while(i<d)
{
 printf("  ");
 i++;
}
//let dd be the number of days in month `month-year`
for(j=1;j<=dd;j++)
{
  if(d<7)                    //to get the sunday date to next line
  {
   printf("%d ",j);
   d++;
  }
  else
  {
   printf("\n");
   printf("%d ",j)
   d=1;
  }

}
```

it will print output in

```
sun mon tue wed thu fri sat
    1    2  3   4   5   6
7
```

form.